# Custom fonts in hybrid mobile app (phone gap) UI

Tags: css, cordova, fonts

I have used few custom fonts in my first hybrid mobile app (in phonegap) using @font-face rules. Font files with different extension were packing with app and called them using CSS. And it rendered perfectly.

But doubtful on  this method and would like to know is this a right approach? Please guide me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using Cordova and that approach for some time now, and never had problems with it. Provided that this is what you're doing...

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: dinpro_black;
    src: url('../fonts/DINPro Black.otf');
}

.font_black {
    font-family:dinpro_black;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mhcarneiro.

That means only .otf is enough for a hybrid mobile app?
My plan is to create app for iPhone, android and windows.

Please confirm

Comment: iPhone and Android, yes. I've built plenty of them and never had a problem. It's a good idea to preload the font so that it doesn't take that half second to show. (Including some text with display:none is my normal strategy). Windows Phone, I can't guarantee what will happen, I haven't tried it before.

Comment: Thanks a lot mhcarneiro!

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an web application in native web view. Web Aplication, so when you using font-face you are using css technology, and is good approach in that kind of apps.