# Telerik Hybrid Mobile App Issue showing Japanese chars in View

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, hybrid-mobile-app, telerik-appbuilder

I am building the HTML5 Hybrid mobile app with the help of Telerik AppBuild platform and in one of the view (components/loginview/view.html) I am trying to show language selection dropdown as follows:

```
<select data-bind="value: addFormData.languagelist" data-role="dropdownlist">
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="ja">日本語</option>
</select>
```

But for my surprise whenever I run the simulator I get the question marks instead of 日本語 characters.

[image]

I checked the main `index.html` file and found that there is proper meta tag like `<meta charset="utf-8" />` present needed to set the charset. I am very much new to this dev platform. So appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different font in your CSS ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28541323/custom-fonts-in-hybrid-mobile-app-phone-gap-ui)). Whichever font you are using doesn't have support for those characters and just leaves the question marks as placeholders.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am not using any extra CSS to decorate my page. Its just a HTML with Japanese chars. The strange thing is it works correctly if I put corresponding hex code as `&#26085;&#26412;&#35486;` instead of those Japanese chars.